# Vertical slide menu in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know how I could create a vertical sliding menu in Angular ?
Like the new facebook sliding menu that comes from left side of the screen.

There are couple of fiddles available but all are for jquery

Comment: Angular won't help you to design a sliding menu... You should start from the existing examples you saw and wrap one of them in an angularjs directive.

Comment: yeah..does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to create a `directive` to do that. You can start with [snap.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html) ([Angular-Snap](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js)).

[DEMO](http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/)

```
<snap-drawer>
  I'm in a drawer!
</snap-drawer>

<snap-content>
  I'm your main content!
</snap-content>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I could wrap this snap.js into a directive and apply it

Comment: Yes, check my `DEMO` and valid my answer ;)

Comment: I can confirm that Snap is by far the most elegant implementation for the left/right drawer functionality for mobile apps and the angular-snap is working smooth for the angularjs apps. I just applied this in my latest app I am working on and is working great.  I tried at least 3 other solutions but undoubtedly Snap is best in all. The plunker above is workin http://run.plnkr.co/wVQJ0NfKEMcPrJO1/ you need to slide by dragging the screen as the toggle link/button is missing

Comment: you can't place a fixed bar inside snap-content.. just lost 1 day trying to fix this..

Comment: you also can't use modals from foundation or bootstrap

Comment: At time of writing, Angular-Snap does not function correctly on Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: both those plunkers are 404ing.